# Samba 3 on Arch Linux, streams_xattr behaviour

Tags: arch-linux, samba, xattr

I'm running Samba 3.6.8-1 on my x64 Arch Linux installation. I recently decided to have my samba share support NTFS's Alternate Data Streams by using `streams_xattr` or `streams_depot`. With `streams_xattr` I discovered that if I copy a file having an ADS from a Win7 box to my samba share, on the Linux console I can see the ADS as an `xattr` attached to the file. However when I copy the file back to my Win7 box using Windows Explorer, there are no ADS entries on it. This is not true if I use `streams_depot`.

Looking at Wireshark captured network traffic  I see that in response to QUERY_FILE_INFO (Query File Stream Info), Samba does not return all streams associated with the file. The response consists of only one stream, which is the file data.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

PS: On a side not, when I first enabled `streams_xattr` (true about `streams_depot` too), I was getting an `NT_STATUS_NETWORK_BUSY` from smbd which was also causing Windows to report an 'unexpected error'.

Upon some research I found this: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7537 . Upon disableing kernel oplocks, this error was gone. I'm wondering if I could still have the kernel oplocks on and there's another way to solve it, since that bug is 2 years old.

UPDATE - I've a Macbook Pro running  OS X Lion (10.7) with Windows filesharing turned on, and I see the same behavior on that too! .. apparently it uses Samba too